# In logrotate, where does postrotate log errors?

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, logrotate

If there are errors in the postrotate script block, where are they logged in Ubuntu?

Comment: If the answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted.  If it hasn't helped, leave a comment and I can follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure any errors are just dumped to stderr.  You should be able to redirect your postrotate to a file with basic I/O redirection.  I'm not sure if Ubuntu has the same file, but there should be an equivalent to the following;

Looking in my `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog`, I see that the `/bin/kill` command's stderr is redirected to `/dev/null`.  There's no reason this couldn't be changed to a regular file descriptor.

```
/bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
```